# About synchronized scope in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

**Objective-C:**

```
@synchronized {
    return;
}
NSLog(@"This line of code does not run.");
```

> Objective-C's @synchronized is a language-level directive and does not introduce a new function scope.

**Swift:**

```
synchronized {
    return
}
print("This line of code does run.")


func synchronized(lock: AnyObject, @noescape closure: () -> Void) {
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    closure()
    objc_sync_exit(lock)
}
```

> Synchronized uses closures which do introduce a function scope.

**Question:**

Can I do the same in Swift? Does not introduce a new function scope.

**Real Problem**

```
public func stopRecording() {

    synchronized(self) {
        guard status == .Recording else { return }
        status = .StoppingRecording
    }

    // Many somethings need to do, and I don`t want to write into the closure.
    finishRecording()
    ......
    ......
    ......
}
```

**Workaround:**

```
if (synchronized(self) { return true }) {
    return
}

print(@"This line of code does not run.")


func synchronized(lock: AnyObject, @noescape closure: () -> Bool) -> Bool {
    objc_sync_enter(lock)
    defer {
        objc_sync_exit(lock)
    }
    return closure()
}
```

Someone has a elegant solution?

Comment: Can you please describe us the real problem?

Comment: appzYourLife, I updated this question :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, your problem is that you want to return from `synchronized`'s caller with the closure you pass it as a parameter. If that's right, then no, there is no better solution than testing the result of `synchronized`.

Answer (score 3):

I just put together a solution that isn't too bad. We cannot introduce a custom language construct that doesn't introduce a new scope, therefore we need to use one of the existing ones. The `if` statement should work for that. I made a small class for that, which does but one thing: Lock the given object and check that the `unlock` method got called before it deallocates (along with some additions for debugging):

```
final class LockingManager {
    let obj: AnyObject

    let file: StaticString
    let line: UInt

    var locked = true

    init(obj: AnyObject, file: StaticString, line: UInt) {
        self.obj = obj
        self.file = file
        self.line = line
        objc_sync_enter(obj)
    }

    func unlock() {
        objc_sync_exit(obj)
        locked = false
    }

    deinit {
        precondition(!locked, "Object \(obj) not unlocked", file: file, line: line)
    }
}
```

With a function like this:

```
func lock(obj: AnyObject, file: StaticString = #file, line: UInt = #line) -> (() -> Void)? {
    return LockingManager(obj: obj, file: file, line: line).unlock
}
```

We can use it like this:

```
if let unlock = lock(obj: self) {
    defer { unlock() }
    // Do stuff
}
```

Since method never returns `nil`, you don't ever want an `else` part. Since the unlock method, which holds the only reference to the `LockingManager`, is only available within the `if` statement, after the statement the `LockingManager` gets deallocated. Upon deallocation, it checks whether the `unlock` method was called and if not, throws an error.

I understand that this isn't a super nice solution, but it does work in that it doesn't introduce a new scope (and additionally checks for correct usage).

Another solution would be to just use simple function calls and a `do` block:

```
do {
    objc_sync_enter(self)
    defer { objc_sync_exit(self) }

    // Do stuff
}
```

I personally prefer the second approach (with some better named functions), because it's much clearer what it does.